# Regex only checks first character in string C#

Tags: c#, regex

Why does the following method only check the first character in the supplied string?

```
public static bool IsUnicodeSms(string message)
{
   var strMap = new Regex(@"^[@£$¥èéùìòÇØøÅå_ÆæßÉ!""#%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>? ¡ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÄÖÑÜ§¿abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzäöñüà^{}\[~]|€]+$");
   return !strMap.IsMatch(message);
}
```

So for example the following string returns false: "abcლ" but "ლabc" returns true.

Comment: did you mean to escape that second last `]`?

Comment: Plus you must escape the  middle `-`, and perhaps the `\`, the `[`, and the `|`

Comment: also i'd recommend using an online tool like https://regex101.com/ to debug regex.

Comment: Here you go - `^[@£$¥èéùìòÇØøÅå_ÆæßÉ!""#%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>? ¡ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÄÖÑÜ§¿abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzäöñüà^{}\[~\]|€]+$`.

Comment: Post it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to escape `]` with `\]` and also put the `-` at the end:

Change this:

```
var strMap = new Regex(@"^[@£$¥èéùìòÇØøÅå_ÆæßÉ!""#%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>? ¡ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÄÖÑÜ§¿abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzäöñüà^{}\[~]|€]+$");
```

To this:

```
var strMap = new Regex(@"^[@£$¥èéùìòÇØøÅå_ÆæßÉ!""#%&'()*+,./0123456789:;<=>? ¡ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÄÖÑÜ§¿abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzäöñüà^{}\[~\]|€-]+$");
```

Btw, you can improve your regex and use:

```
var strMap = new Regex(@"^[@£$¥èéùìòÇØøÅå_ÆæßÉ!"#%&'()*+,./\w:;<=>? ¡ÄÖÑÜ§¿äöñüà^{}\[~\]|€-]+$");
```

And not sure if using the ignore case flag might help you to shorten it a little more like this:

```
var strMap = new Regex(@"(?i)^[@£$¥èéùìòÇøå_Ææß!"#%&'()*+,./\w:;<=>? ¡§¿äöñüà^{}\[~\]|€-]+$");
```

Comment: these regexes don't match empty strings, which may be desirable

Comment: @Armand that's very easy to do, just change `]+$");` by `]*$");`

Comment: I know, just didn't want to edit your answer.  I also suspect that this doesn't match the newline character, which AFAIK is a valid character.

Comment: @Armand well, this question was resolved two months ago I guess OP already solved this question, and also if he marked this answer as the right one I guess it helped too. However, thank you for pointing that.

Comment: Not getting at you.  SO is a reference, as well as helping the OP with their problem.  These comments are for people referring to the question in future.

Answer (score 2):

You copied the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921013/checking-if-sms-message-is-in-standard-gsm-alphabet).

It's very flawed. It needs more escaping. From [Regexp Tutorial - Character Classes or Character Sets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

> the only special characters or metacharacters inside a character class are the closing bracket (]), the backslash (\), the caret (^), and the hyphen (-)

So, it needs to be:

```
new Regex(@"^[@£$¥èéùìòÇØøÅå_ÆæßÉ!""#%&'()*+,\-./0123456789:;<=>? ¡ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÄÖÑÜ§¿abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzäöñüà^{}\[~\]|€]+$");
```

You can of course improve the regex even further like @Fede demonstrates.